# printing the function is producing output but call it is not (python)

Tags: python, function, calling-convention

This function, when printed, outputs 7 but when called, does not output anything. Can someone please explain why this is happening?

```
def myfunc(x, y):
    return (x+y)
 
myfunc(3,4)
```

This does not output anything. But if I write `print(myfunc(3,4))`, the output is `7`. How does this work?

Answer (score 0):

Well it does the computation and returns the value.

But since you do not print it it just stays there.
The function executes but it does not print to console.
Simple as that

Comment: Hi Göktürk, add also some code lines on how would you solve the problem, so your answer will look more complete (not just "commenting" it)

Comment: My friend, you are a genius. Thank you so much!

Comment: @cards makes sense thx